# Cannot vertically center navigation bar within a CSS grid box

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, css-grid

I have been trying to figure this problem out for a while now. I will best be able to explain it if I actually represent it visually:

I am trying to vertically align my navigation bar.

[image]

I have tried using `align-self` however nothing seems to be changing.

```
/* Navigation */

.navigation {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  align-self: center;
}

.navigation a {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.navigation a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* Hide the link that should open and close the navigation on small screens */
.navigation .icon {
    display: none;
}
```

Is this a case of me getting confused with my css, or a case with incorrect div positioning?

```
<!-- Navigation bar -->

    <div class="navigation" id="myNavigation">
      <a href="index.html">Home</a>
      <a href="#services">About Me</a>
      <a href="#about-me">Services</a>
      <a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="openNavigation()">&#9776;</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I have found the solution. I needed to make my css grid `display: flex` and `align-items: center`.